Make expressions equal to 24 using exactly two 3s and two 8s

You will use both 3s and both 8s to make expressions that equal 24.

Addition is allowed.

Subtraction is allowed.

Negation is allowed if it does not violate number 16 below in the list.

Multiplication is allowed.

Division is allowed.  Use "/" or the horizontal fraction bar.

The regular factorial is allowed only.  The factorial of a factorial is done
by (X!)! or ((expression)!)! if the need arises.

Grouping symbols such as parentheses are allowed.

You may concatenate digits only.

You may not use any decimals.

You may not use square roots or other roots.

You may not use exponentiation.

You may not use logarithms.

You may not use trigonometric functions.

You may not use any other numbers, characters, functions, or operations.

Forms of AxB, A - B, etc. will not be seen as essentially different from
forms of BxA, -B + A, etc., respectively.

This is in base ten.


Please try to come up with at least 20 essentially different solutions
other than

 $  \ \ 8/(3 - 8/3).$


If I have another solution, do I post it separately, or tack it on as an edit?

You may post it separately if you would like.

Why the downvotes? This is famously one of the hardest 24 puzzles, now with more operations allowed.

Stop changing the goal. If you want to ask a new question, ask a new question.

@ bobble -- Changing the goal of the number of solutions and asking a new question are entirely different things.

By extending, it's become even more of an open-ended question. After a few more are found, will you up the target again?

@Weather Vane -- Negative.  There will be no more extensions of goal targets.

I propose rolling back to the original question which asked for 10 solutions before some answers were posted. I could use my rep, but would like some concensus. In the meantime, I have downvoted.

@Weather Vane -- I propose Weather Vane remove his proposal, as he has been unduly critical and argumentative, despite helpful suggestions toward solutions being given to him.  He is being petty.

I won't do that but I have deleted my answer. Please refer to the discussions on open-ended questions on meta here and here.

Kinda a trivial comment, but you'd also have to forbid repeatedly stacking factorials on ones and twos from counting as different solutions.

@Benjamin Wang -- What I added in the edit to the puzzle description just now is not a change in the puzzle, because I never was allowing what you described anyway, because those extraneous factorial symbols  would have made those solutions not essentially different.

I feel like defining "essentially different" is an important part of enforcing solutions that are "essentially different".

@Someone -- In the context of the post to Mr. Wang, attaching more factorial symbols to the ones and twos do not change itheir values but only their appearances.  The additional symbols are not essential to make a different value.

I will openly reveal any remaining solutions under "Answer Your Question" on Sunday.

Here are three more solutions:

 $$\biggl(\dfrac8{8-3-3}\biggr)!$$
$$\dfrac{(8-3)!}{8-3}$$
$$\biggl(\dfrac8{8-(3!-3)!}\biggr)!$$


Open hint: There is another one that resembles your top solution.  The same numbers are in the same places in the fraction, but there are a couple of additional factorial signs in the denominator and another pair of grouping symbols.

That's certainly a weird-looking third solution, but it works. And I think it's the one you intended.

Someone, yes, that is the one.  Thank you.  I would click another "up arrow" next to your solution box for that if I could.

I came up with 5:

1. $38 - 8 - 3!$
2. $8 \cdot 3! - 8 \cdot 3$
3. $3! \cdot 8 / 3 + 8$
4. $3! \cdot (8/8 + 3)$
5. $8/(3/3!) + 8$


Open hint for an additional one:  Multiplying by 8/3 is the same as dividing by?

I thought that would be considered equivalent, similar to the addition/subtraction ones.

@Someone -- Please look at the fifth one.  Since that makes use of a number divided by a fraction, I don't want to leave out a similar type.  You may post it and get credit if you like.

I have one more solution

 $ 24 = (8!/((3!)!*8)-3)! $

and 2 more based on the hint

 In above solution 8/8 can be replaced by (8-8)!
$ 24 = (3!-3+(8-8)!)! $
$ 24 = 3!*((8-8)!+3)  $

and one more

 $ 24 = (8!/((3!)!*(8+3!)))! $


Your first solution is really cool. It would have the highest intermediate number reached during the calculation.

The top solution and the recent fourth solution are each at a similar  level of or "neighbors level" of complexity.

Here is another few

1. $(3!-3+ (8/8))! $
2. $3!*8/(8-3!) $
3. $(8+8-3!-3!)! $
4. $((8-3!)*(8-3!))! $

We Need 5 more

@ Mike -- I have increased the request for the number of solutions to 20, because you solvers are very clever.

Mike, this is an open hint for you or for anyone else:           Factorial of the quantity         [8 minus (expression that equals 4)]


 $3!/(3/8) + 8$



$(8 - 3*8/(3!))!$


When my answer was proposed/edited by Someone to hide it from view, the solutions were left right next to each other.  I hit a button, and now they are separated from each other.

@bobble -- No thank you.  Thank you for offering it.

@bobble -- When the comment directly under my problem title changes to "Asked 7 days ago," will I have clearance to post a new question at that time?

@bobble -- No, I meant the rule is people are supposed to only post up to the limit of one question per week.  And, I wanted to be ready to post my next question when the week would be finished.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
